# SP2013 Custom List - Case Sensitive Filter with JQuery

Tags: jquery, custom-list, filter

Good Morning Friends;

I am using a JQuery script to act as a filter on a custom list. The text in my custom list is all Uppercase. Currently the filter is case sensitive. I tried using text-transform to uppercase, which indeed transforms the text in the box. However, the filter still will not work unless CAPS Lock is on, on my keyboard.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript"src="SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //attach a function to the keyup event on the filter box
    $('#filterInput').keyup(function() 
    {
        var inputVal = $('#filterInput').val():
        DynamicFilter(inputVal.toUpperCase());
    });
})

//strip off html taqs
function stripHTML (field) {
    return field.replace(/<([^>]+)>/g,'');
}

function DynamicFilter(text)
{
    //find out list view (default class for a listview is "ms-listviewtable"
    $('table [class="ms-listviewtable"]').find('tr').each(function()
        {
            //don't filter out the header row
            if ($(this).attr("class") != "ms-viewheadertr ms-vhltr")
            {
                //get the html for the row and strip off the html tabs
                source = stripHTML($(this).html());

                //check to see if the filter text exists in the remaining text
                if (source.indexOf(text) < 0)
                {
                    //hide the row if it doesn't contain the text
                    $(this).hide();
                } else {
                    //otherwise show it
                    $(this).show();
                }
            }
        }
    );
}

</script>

<div id="mainDiv">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class='Filter' width='125px'>Search: <input type="Text" id="filterInput" ></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using below code. It should work in your case:

```
$('#filterInput').keyup(function() 
{ 
    var inputVal = $('#filterInput').val():
    DynamicFilter(inputVal.toUpperCase());
});
```

Comment: Should I keep the Text Transform action?

Comment: When I add this to the original code, the filter does not work. Unless I added it wrong?

Comment: You don't need text transform in this case.try adding without using transform.

Comment: Can you add it to the original code? I'm worried I'm not doing it right as it does not work.

Comment: I updated the code sample on the main post, with what I am using with your suggestion.